# ubuntu automatically switches between apps

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, window-manager

I have the ubuntu 22.04 LTS version.

My issue is that my distro automatically switches between apps.
To make it more clear, when I'm working with VSCode and I get a notification on Microsoft teams or Telegram, ubuntu automatically brings up that application.

it's very annoying for me. is there any solution to disable this feature?

```
| OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
| OS Type: 64-bit
| GNOME Version: 42.1
| Windowing system: x11
```

Comment: Try following command: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock workspace-agnostic-urgent-windows false`. Let me know if this solves the issue. If it does, I will turn this comment into an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.